# I want to make a border like this please click on the link to see the border

Tags: html, css

The border has the cut edges on the left side. Here is the border I want to make:

[image]

Here is my code, what changes do I have to make?

```
 <section class="started">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="box1 text-center">
              <h3>All started in 1956</h3>
              <h3>A fresh breeze of modern furniture in town!</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
.box1 {
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.box1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 12px solid #000000;
  border-left: 12px solid #000000;
  border-right: 12px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #000000;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have code? We can't help you fix anything if we can't see what's broken.

Comment: Here is the html of the code

Comment: Not sure you can do that very easily.  You probably will have to use linear gradients.

Comment: How does the html code you've provided fit in with the example image ? There is no text on your image. Would there be text in it ? It would be trivial to create whats shown on the image, but i imagine that isn't the actual endgame; you'll need to give some more context as to what you're trying to make in order to supply actual useful hints/code.

Comment: Okay please help me how to make this with linear gradients do you've any idea?

Comment: Hey raxi I've edited the picture link here is the whole scenario which I've to make . You can see the picture by clicking on the link,.

Answer (score 2):

## use `::before` Pseudo-Selector

I use the trick of `::before` Pseudo Element in CSS, because is Create a New Element with we can style it, to do what you want :)

1. create a border in your parent element (in my case `.container`)
2. get the thickness of the border

example: `border: 0.5em solid black;` is the **0.5em** (you probably have the number is in pixel)

3. create a `::before` or `::after` PseudoElement
4. add the value of thickness of border to the `width` of `::before`
5. set the parent to `position: relative` so we can use `absolute` for the PseudoElement
6. set the Parent `.container` to `display: grid;` so we can easily center this PseudoElement with `place-items: center;`

#### now the real trick is here

when you use this lines:

```css
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  width: 0.5em;
```

## Complete Code

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border: 0.5em solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you mate You've solved my problem . Thank you once again mate. ! God bless You! @Laaouatni Anas

Comment: @AbdurrafaySaqlain now I also put a Detailed Explanation :) appreciate this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To make a box like that with a missing segment, this would be one approach, although the linear-gradient might have to be adjust for browser compatibility.

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  }
 #border-segment {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 height:1px;
 width:100%;

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 33%, #FFFFFF 33%, #FFFFFF 66%, #000000 66%, #000000 100%);

 }
```

```html
<div class="box"><div id = "border-segment"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SScotti . really Appreciate your efforts ! happy coding! Your code helps me alot tooo.